# How do I declare the variable in the package.json file in the quasar framework and show it in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I want to declare a variable in package.json and route according to the variable.

```json
// package.json

  "scripts": {

    "electron:build:HI": "cross-env example=HI quasar dev -m electron -d",
    "electron:build:HELLO": "cross-env example=HELLO quasar dev -m electron -d",

  },
```

```js
// routes.js
...
const route = [
      {
        path: 'document-before-billA',
        component: () => process.env.example === 'HI' ? import(`@/pages/documentDownload/DocumentBeforeBill${example}.vue`) : ''
      },
      {
        path: 'document-before-billB',
        component: () => process.env.example === 'HELLO' ? import(`@/pages/documentDownload/DocumentBeforeBill${example}.vue`) : ''
      }
]
```

I've tried cross-env, but it doesn't work.
Is there a way to dynamically allocate it in quasar.config.js?
Please let me know if you can use another library.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

```json
...
  "scripts": {
    "electron:build:HI": "cross-env example=HI quasar dev -m electron -d",
  },
...
```

```
quasar.config.js
...
env : {
 example: process.env.example
}
...
```

it work !